# ENONET error while running jest-preset-angular

Tags: angular, jest-preset-angular

I am trying to integrate jest for my angular project for unit testing.

I followed the instructions from [this link](https://www.xfive.co/blog/testing-angular-faster-jest/).

I am facing a weird error as `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\source-code\packages\core\src\view\ng_module.ts'` when i run.

My folder structure doesnt have a folder named **package**.After a lot of digging i found that `packages\core\src\view\ng_module.ts'` is used by a npm package(angular :P)[image: screenshot of the path used in angular]

i dont know how this error is being thrown which doesnt happen when i run through karma

This is my config for jest

    `"jest": {
        "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
        "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts",
        "globals": {
            "ts-jest": {
                "tsConfigFile": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                "useBabelrc": true
            },
            "__TRANSFORM_HTML__": true
        },
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.(ts|html)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-preset-angular/preprocessor.js",
            "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
        },
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(@ngrx|ngx-dialog|ng-infinity))"
        ]
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Time to answer my own question.

It seems to be a version issue.

At the time of writing this answer, the latest version is:

```
 "@types/jest": "^22.0.1",
 "jest": "^22.0.4",
 "jest-preset-angular": "^5.0.0"
```

The one which supports my project(in angular v4) is:

```
"@types/jest": "^20.0.7",
"jest": "^20.0.4",
"jest-preset-angular": "^2.0.5"
```

after this those errors stopped to occur.

I checked this result againt [this git repo too](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/ng2-diary-book)(also written in ng4) :P. Once i changed the jest version to latest in that repo, it too stared giving the same weird path `packages\core\src\....` error.

But some new errors started to happen now. I am using `jest.spyOn().mockReturnValue()` which throws errors in actual component function, which shouldnt be case, since the function call should be mocked and use the provided return value. I tried with `jest.spyOn().mockImplementation()` too but with no success.

I suspect with the `spyOn` methods to cause the errors.